# Recursion in python, without overwriting changed variable

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function that does the following:

If **player_hand** doesn't have any number that is less than or equal to **mana_bank** the function should do nothing.

If **player_hand** has a number that is less than or equal to **mana_bank** then the function should prompt the user with which number he chooses.

If the number the user chooses is less than **mana_bank** it should return a list with that number. If the number is more than **mana_bank** it should call the function again untill he prompts a number that is less than or equal to **mana_bank**.

Whenever I run the function and the user first prompts a number that is higher than **mana_bank** the function gets called from within itself, and then even if the user prompts a number lower than or equal to **mana_bank**, the function returns None instead of the number in a list.

I also tried making the variable **player_choice** global but it still didn't work.

Would appreciate any guidance.

```
def pick_card():
    player_choice_str = 0
    player_choice = []
    for i in player_hand:
        if i <= mana_bank:
            print(player_hand, mana_bank, "Mana available type the name of the card you wish to play ... ")
            player_choice_str = input()
            break
        if not i <= mana_bank:
            return "You don't have enough mana to play a card."
    if int(player_choice_str) > mana_bank:
        print("That card costs " + str(player_choice_str) + " and you only have " + str(mana_bank) + " this round.")
        pick_card()
    if int(player_choice_str) <= mana_bank:
        player_choice.append(player_choice_str)
        return player_choice



player_hand = [4, 8, 8]
mana_bank = 4

print(pick_card())
```

Comment: Just for your info, the user can crash your program with a `RecursionError` if giving a number greater than `mana_bank` too many times. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for processing the user input properly.

Comment: If player has multiple cards <= mana_bank, should they be prompted for each card or just once overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that `player_choice` is defined locally. It will be overwritten in every function call. In addition, you have to evaluate/return the return value of pick_card() in the case when the players choice is greater than the manabank. Otherwise the first called function of the recursion will return `None` because of the missing return value.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop you have both conditions - `if i <= mana_bank:` and `if not i <= mana_bank:` and for any given `i` one of these will be true.

So your loop will stop as soon as it hits a card that is greater than `mana_bank` and won't check all cards.

What you want to do is:

```
for i in player_hand:
    if i <= mana_bank:
        print(player_hand, mana_bank, "Mana available type the name of the card you wish to play ... ")
        player_choice_str = input()
        break
if player_choice_str is 0:             # no card selected at the end of the loop
    return "You don't have enough mana to play a card."
```

Also you will probably want to validate the user input after this line `player_choice_str = input()` to check they entered a valid card.